# Can a rogue's sneak attack feature be used on objects?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack, objects

The Rogue's [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) says

> Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe’s distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.
>
> You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll.

So my question is can it be used to deal extra damage to objects with normal HP.

> The object in question in case it matters is the Soulmonger from Tomb of Annihilation

Comment: Lodge (the DM): [narrating] "Flynn is alone with the Grimoire."

Leo (Flynn's player): "I stab it! Wait! I BACKSTAB it!"

Lodge: "Y-y-you can't backstab it! You can't *sneak-attack* an inanimate object!"

Leo: "Why not? It's PRONE!"

Lodge: "It doesn't have a discernible anatomy!"

Leo: "It's got a SPINE! Doesn't it?"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Sneak Attack only works against creatures

The [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) feature states:

> Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and **exploit a foe’s distraction.** Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one **creature** you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.
>
> You don’t need advantage on the attack roll if another **enemy of the target** is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn’t incapacitated, and you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll.

The feature is described as exploiting a foe's distraction; you can't distract inanimate objects. Additionally the feature explicitly requires you to damage a *creature* and not an object. Finally the section on when you don't need advantage involves an enemy of your target; objects don't (typically) have enemies. Both the description of the feature and its mechanics prevent it from being used against objects.

---

That said, your GM may rule otherwise for things such as sentient (animate) objects or even the artefact in question here.

Answer (score 10):

## No

From the Sneak Attack feature (emphasis added):

> you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to **one creature** you hit

Objects are not creatures, and so Sneak Attack does not work on objects. Unless your DM is lenient, of course.