# Does Sword of Sharpness's maximize damage rule apply to a Rogue’s Sneak Attack damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

If a rogue hits someone with a scimitar of sharpness and the preconditions for sneak attack are in place, does the rogue also get to maximize the damage of sneak attacks?

For reference the [Sword of Sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-sharpness) states:

> When you attack an object with this magic sword and hit, maximize your weapon damage dice against the target. [...]

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Perhaps of note to you is that [Sneak Attack does not work on objects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162752) while a Sword of Sharpness only maximizes weapon damage dice against objects, not creatures.

Comment: Can we edit the question to only apply to sneak attack and reopen? @Someone_Evil

Comment: I’ve voted to close the other question for needs more focus, as such features should be evaluated individually rather than generally since every feature is different.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That would still be an explicitly mentioned part of the linked question, but that other question (or its answers) might need a lot more work.