# Does the Savage Attacker feat let you reroll Sneak Attack damage dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, damage, sneak-attack, melee-combat

The [Savage Attacker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/savage-attacker) feat (PHB, p. 169) states:

> Once per turn when you roll damage for a melee weapon attack, you can reroll the weapon’s damage dice and use either total.

---

Additionally, the [rogue's Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#SneakAttack) feature states:

> Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe’s distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an **extra 1d6 damage** to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

---

Considering that Sneak Attack damage deals the same kind of damage as the weapon, would Savage Attacker benefit it and let you reroll the Sneak Attack extra damage dice?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### No, it would not

The Weapon's damage dice is different from the total damage dice.

Savage Attacker works with allowing reroll on the weapon's damage dice.

Sneak attack and it's associated dice are a different mechanic and represent extra damage on top of the Weapon dice: it is not *part of* the weapon dice.

This makes sense from a rules perspective, but it also supported by [Jeremy Crawford via Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/679830252005101568):

> Savage Attacker is meant to apply to the weapon's damage dice only

#### An example of language for when all dice are applicable

[Critical hits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Rolling1or20) are clear in their specificity to double *all* of the damage dice (emphasis mine):

> Roll **all of the attack's damage dice** twice and add them together.

The wording here is clear in that *all* of the dice are to be rolled again and that it is applies to more than just weapon dice.

Comment: Similarly, half-orc's extra crit damage dice is worded the same  way

Comment: @PremierBromanov Yeah, it's pretty clear when they differentiate weapon from attack damage. Except for [GWF](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/what-exactly-does-great-weapon-fighting-allow-you-to-reroll) where it doesn't specify weapon in the langauge, but Sage Advice has clarified they meant it (but didn't errata it.) I still believe GWF should work with total attack damage dice.

Comment: @CuthbertCooper: No, it says "you can reroll the weapon's damage dice" explicitly.